# [Vue warn]: Property or method "names" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up a Vue.js project and connecting it to Firebase for the real time database.

Problem: I am able to save the data to the Firebase database however I am not able to render it to the view.

Error Message:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "names" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render.

I have tried to adjust the `vue` instance "names" property by adding it the data function instead of making it a separate property in the instance, but that is not working.

```html
<div id="app">

    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" v-model="name">
    <button @click="submitName()">Submit</button>


    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="personName of names"
            v-bind:key="personName['.key']">
            {{personName.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

```js
<script>

import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    names: namesRef
  },
  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style>
```

Expected Result: Data saved to Firebase is rendered on the view

Actual result:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "names" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Comment: Did my solution resolve this issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you have an incorrect `attribute` in your `Vue` instance.. You need to move `firebase` into `data`..

([[CodePen]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/jogzGR?editors=1010))

I was unable to get this working in a Stack Snippet..

***~~~THE FIX~~~***

---

***VUE/JS***

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://UR-DATABASE.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "UR-DATABASE"
});

const database = firebase.database().ref("/users");

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    firebase: {
      names: []
    },
    name: "SomeName"
  },
  methods: {
    getFirebaseUsers() {
      this.firebase.names = [];
      database.once("value", users => {
        users.forEach(user => {
          this.firebase.names.push({
            name: user.child("name").val(),
            id: user.child("id").val()
          });
        });
      });
    },
    handleNameAdd() {
      let id = this.generateId();
      database.push({
        name: this.name,
        id: id
      });
      this.name = "";
      this.getFirebaseUsers();
    },
    generateId() {
      let dt = new Date().getTime();
      return "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
        let r = ((dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16) | 0;
        dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
        return (c == "x" ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8).toString(16);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getFirebaseUsers();
  }
});
```

***HTML***

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase.js"> . 
  </script>

  <div id="app">

    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" v-model="name">
    <button @click="handleNameAdd">Submit</button>


    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(person, index) in firebase.names"
            v-bind:key="person.id">
            {{person.name}} | {{person.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

---

---

---

***OLD ANSWER:***
This is what it should look like inside of `data`:

```
...
data() {
  firebase: {
    names: [],
  }
}
...
```

Therefore, the data in your `v-for` would be referenced via `firebase.names` like:

```
...
<li v-for="(personName, index) in firebase.names"
  :key="index">         // <<-- INDEX IS NOT THE BEST WAY TO STORE KEYS BUT ITS BETTER THAN NOTHING 
  //:key="personName.id // <<-- YOU COULD ALSO DO SOMETHING LIKE THAT, IF YOU HAVE A UNIQUE ID PER PERSON
  {{personName.name}}
</li>
...
```

---

---

***OPTIMAL FIX:***

You could use a `computed` property if you wanted to automatically save/retrieve data from firebase each time a user adds a new name...as outlined in the CodePen and Code Snippet..

---

---

***THE ISSUE:***

```
<script>
import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
    }
  },
  firebase: {        //  <<--- THIS IS INVALID, AND WHY IT'S NOT RENDERING
    names: namesRef  //        CHECK YOUR CONSOLE FOR ERRORS
  },
  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

---

Comment: @MattOestrich I tried your first option and it does remove the error but I am still not seeing the data that I saved being represented on the view. 

`<script>

import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      firebase: {
          names: [],
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>`

Comment: That is because you aren't using a `computed` property... You have to reach out to Firebase each time you want to get updated data..

Comment: Please see my [updated CodePen here](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/jogzGR?editors=1010) - I am unable to add this as a snippet, but this example shows how you can accomplish this.

Comment: @iivriandre I have updated my original answer to reflect these changes.. I was wrong about the `computed` property, but did find a resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You need  to return the object in data

```
<script>

import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
      firebase: {
       names: namesRef
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property for `names`.  `Computed` is more appropriate than `data` in this case, mainly because the component does not `own` the data.  If it eventually resided in a vuex store, for instance, it would then react to external changes.

```html
<script>

import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
    }
  },
  computed: {
    names() {
      return namesRef
    }
  }
  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

import {namesRef} from './firebase'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
    }
  },
  cumputed: {
    names: namesRef
  },
  methods: {
    submitName() {
      namesRef.push( {name:this.name, edit:false} )
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i got this error `Getter is missing for computed property "names".`  when i changed firebase to computed

Answer (score 0):

Got mine working.

The solution is pretty simple.

Add `names:[]` to data object so it looks like:

```
...
  data () {
    return {
      name: "levi",
      names:[]
    }
  },
....
```

That's pretty much it.

**Explaination**

*The firebase object data needs to be defined in order to use it*

If you have more issues check the [vuex documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/#why) replicate that to your code.